# Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reactor.core.scheduler.TimedScheduler

Tags: java, spring, reactive

While writing a test case for testing a Flux service, I am facing the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reactor.core.scheduler.TimedScheduler
```

My code is like:

```
FluxExchangeResult<Event> result = webTestClient.get()
.uri("/events")
.accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
.exchange()
.expectStatus()
.isOk()
.returnResult(Event.class);

Flux<Event> eventFlux = result.getResponseBody();
StepVerifier.create(eventFlux)
.expectNextCount(10)
.expectComplete()
.verify();
```

I have the following dependencies in the pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>  
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor.addons</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Have someone faced and resolved a similar issue?
I took a reference from the Dzone article:https://dzone.com/articles/spring-webflux-a-basic-crud-application-part-1

Comment: Your reactor versions must match in the pom

Comment: Specifically, `reactor-spring` is deprecated. https://github.com/reactor/reactor-spring#reactor-spring

Answer (score 3):

I used a wrong dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor.addons</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The correct one is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The one which appears as the top search for google is probably for some other use.

Comment: Adding this dependency solved my problem in my case: <dependency>
   <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
   <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.9.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 2):

`reactor-test` currently only goes up to `3.0.7.RELEASE`, which includes `reactor-core:3.0.7.RELEASE` itself.

You will encounter classes not being found when versions do not match.

Therefore, you can do this

```
<properties>
    <reactor.version>3.0.7.RELEASE</reactor.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        <version>${reactor.version}</version>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.addons</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <version>${reactor.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However, you might want to start at [this documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#getting) to get the latest compatible versions.